# the following settings were applied to the project on the settings for the local instance of iis express

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdDyj.png)

Hi,

I am getting the above error as soon as I open the application (VS 2013 project).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get rid of the message, close VS, delete the applicationhost.config file from your local system, open VS again (not the project/solution) and if you use TFS, get recurring latest version on that file.